# Comprehensive references on partial differential equations

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

How do the three volumes by Taylor's "Partial differential equations" compare with the two volumes with the same title by Friedrich Sauvigny's as a reference for study?

What are the good and bad points of each and are there more comprehensive references?

Answer (score 6):

I think neither texts are bad, but they focus on different approaches towards PDE. I suggest you talk to a faculty member specialized in PDE to ask his or her opinion on it. I think Evans is a standard reference for first year graduate level PDE. After that one needs to learn a lot of tools like harmonic analysis, geometric analysis, etc to understand PDE in general properly. Also I believe both are more suitable as reference books than textbooks, as it took considerable amount of time for the student to finish either of them (Taylor's 3 volume contains a lot of material).